# Connecting AirPods Pro in Linux Ubuntu

Tags: sound, bluetooth

I recently have been going through many problems connecting my AirPods to my Ubuntu (22.04) pc, I already tried changing ControllerMode to bredr, which helped for a while, but now that by itself isn't working anymore, now I cant seen to find any other way around this issue.
Sometimes the bluetooth even "connects", but no sound comes of it and I cant even find them in the available speakers, even went through pc config not responding after the connection happened.